# Syntax file: keywords within context

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

I have a language which uses statement like

```
WHILE ... DO
..
END_WHILE
```

I can do the following in the corresponding synthax file

```
syn keyword LangKeys WHILE DO END_WHILE
syn region  LangBlock start="WHILE" end="END_WHILE" fold transparent
```

which allows me to highlight correctly the different keywords as well as defining a given region.

But now, I would like to be sure that the DO is only highlighted **in the context of the loop**. But I don't want to affect anything else. I tried

```
syn keyword LangKeys WHILE END_WHILE
syn keyword InsideKeys DO contained
syn region LangBlock start="WHILE" end="END_WHILE" fold transparent contained=InsideKeys
```

also without the `transparent` option. I tried a few variations of that. But it does not produce the expected result.

**How can I get the highlight to be applied only when the keywords are within a given context?**

Alternatively, is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: Which language is this? Perhaps there's already a syntax file floating around somewhere?

Comment: In this case, it is the Structure Control Language (SCL) for Siemens S7 PLC. But I have met a similar problem, for example for modelica.

Answer (score 1):

The difference isn't so large, but the following seems to be working

```
syn keyword LangKeys   contained WHILE END_WHILE
syn keyword InsideKeys contained DO
syn region  LangBlock  fold transparent 
        \ matchgroup=LangKeys 
        \ start="\<WHILE\_s" end="\<END_WHILE\>" 
        \ contains=InsideKeys
hi def link LangKeys   Statement
hi def link InsideKeys Statement
```

That way, a `DO` inside the `WHILE` group will be highlighted but not separated.

Comment: The `keyword LangKeys` part should not be required.

Comment: @Vitor, why not? I use them as matchgroup, and in my tests, without it, you would have `DO` highlighted, but `WHILE` and `ENd_WHILE` would take on the `transparent` feature...

Answer (score 1):

```
syn region LangBlock matchgroup=LangKeys start="\<WHILE\>" end="\<END_WHILE\>" fold transparent contains=InsideKeys
syn keyword InsideKeys DO contained
```

Things that I changed in the syntax code you provided:

1. The `\< \>` are required to only match words, such that WHILE is not found inside END_WHILE.
2. The `matchgroup` argument sets the syntax group name to be used in the match start/end words.
3. Remove the keywords for WHILE and END_WHILE, because the highlight is done by the respective syn-match command.

Obviously, both `LangKeys` and `InsideKeys` syntax groups need to be defined using the `highlight` command with something like the following:

```
highlight link LangKeys   Statement
highlight link InsideKeys Statement
```

For more information please check:

```
:help syn-match
:help hi-link
```

Comment: You have LangKeys in your `matchgroup`, where do you define them?

Comment: The original question does not include highlight commands and it is said that it works, so I assume that there is no doubt regarding that part.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to say. Indeed the question does not specify highlighting. Nevertheless, in your example, you have `syn region LangBlock matchgroup=LangKeys ...`. I might be mistaken, but I think that this calls for another  `syn` line with `LangKeys` defined. Doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't and I  explain that in my answer in the second point.

Comment: No, you don't really explain it. At least not clearly enough. So you could have `matchgroup=FooBar` instead, it would just work the same?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have a `:highlight` named FooBar, that would work perfectly.

Comment: Just noticed that you answered your own question :)

Comment: I did, as I did not get any other answer and my system seems to be doing what I wanted.