# folding in matlab

Tags: folding, matlab, keyword, syntax

I'm using vim for my matlab editor. And It works nicely, except I cannot get folding to work.

I found my syntax file on github: [matlab.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/matlab.vim)

And I wanted to add folding.

I changed the line

```
syn region matlabMultilineComment   start=+%{+ end=+%}+ contains=matlabTodo,matlabTab
```

to

```
syn region matlabMultilineComment   start=+%{+ end=+%}+ fold contains=matlabTodo,matlabTab
```

And this works, `zm` now folds multiline comments!. So now I wanted to add folding for blocks

Starting on:

- `if`
- `for`
- `switch`
- `while`

ending on:

- `end`
  and also between `%%` and `%%`

So I went from having

```
syn keyword matlabLabel         case switch
syn keyword matlabConditional       else elseif end if otherwise
syn keyword matlabRepeat        do for while
```

to have

```
syn keyword matlabLabel         case switch
syn keyword matlabConditional       else elseif if otherwise
syn keyword matlabEnd           end
syn keyword matlabRepeat        do for while
syn region matlabSection 
            \start=+%%+ 
            \end=+%%+ 
            \fold 
syn region matlabIfBlock        
            \matchgroup=matlabConditional 
            \start="if" 
            \end="end" 
            \transparent 
            \fold
```

This however, does not fold neither my if statement, nor my `%%` section (my `%{` `%}` multiline comment is folding nicely)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not complete, but might help:

The `coolword` in `start="coolword"` apparently cannot be a `keyword` to ommit this use the `matchgroup` ability, to mark the start word as a certain group. The endword can however be a keyword.

Also, ensure to use the `\<` and `\>` flags as described here: [Syntax file: keywords within context](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5418/syntax-file-keywords-within-context)
Such that the words will not be taken out of context.

Now I have:

```
syn keyword matlabLabel         case
syn keyword matlabConditional       else elseif  otherwise
syn keyword matlabRepeat        do
syn keyword matlabFunction      error eval 
syn region matlabSection
            \ start="%%"
            \ end="%%"
            \ fold
syn region matlabIfBlock
            \ matchgroup=matlabConditional
            \ start="\<if\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
syn region matlabForLoop
            \ matchgroup=matlabRepeat
            \ start="\<for\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
syn region matlabForLoop
            \ matchgroup=matlabRepeat
            \ start="\<while\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
syn region matlabForLoop
            \ matchgroup=matlabRepeat
            \ start="\<parfor\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold

syn region matlabSwitch
            \ matchgroup=matlabLabel
            \ start="\<switch\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
syn region matlabFunctionBlock
            \ matchgroup=matlabFunction
            \ start="\<function\>"
            \ end="\<end\>"
            \ transparent
            \ fold
"syn match matlabCellComment     "^.*$"
```

the last line is commented out. It used to include `%%` and thus make the folding of `%%` sections impossible (And I'm too much of a vim noob to know what letting the remains be would do, so I eradicated it).